# Is there a way to find all the loaded and unloaded cogs in discord.py-rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a lot of cogs for my bot, but i load and unload them using commands

Still I get confused and load/unload a cog again-and-again

I wonder is there a way to check all the loaded and unloaded cogs using commands.(Other than the default help command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if you try to load a cog that is already loaded,
it will raise a [`discord.ext.commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load#discord.ext.commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded) exception. Using this error, you could do this:

```py
from discord import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def check_cogs(ctx, cog_name):
    try:
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{cog_name}")
    except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
        await ctx.send("Cog is loaded")
    except commands.ExtensionNotFound:
        await ctx.send("Cog not found")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Cog is unloaded")
        bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{cog_name}")
```

PS: your cogs will need to be in a `cogs` folder for this code to work.