# Python Discord Bot: Why does try except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded: not trigger code under it?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command for my discord bot where I can list all the cogs in my cogs folder and display whether they are loaded or not.

Using [this overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036583/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-loaded-and-unloaded-cogs-in-discord-py-rewrite) I came up with the code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@cogs.command(name='list')
async def cogs_list(ctx):
    cog_list = ''
    for extension in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if extension.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension[:-3]}')
            except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** loaded\n'
            else:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** not loaded\n'
                client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send(f'**BOT COGS:**\n{cog_list}')
```

I was able to get a proper response when the cog was loaded but when I was checking an unloaded cog I got no response from the bot and I got the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ExtensionNotLoaded: Extension 'cogs.administrator.py' has not been loaded.
```

I tried revising the code using except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@cogs.command(name='list')
async def cogs_list(ctx):
    cog_list = ''
    for extension in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if extension.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension[:-3]}')
            except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** loaded\n'
            except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** not loaded\n'
                client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send(f'**BOT COGS:**\n{cog_list}')
```

Now it properly shows whether the extension is loaded or not, but it fails to unload the cog when it triggers 'except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded'. (so the first run it says the cog is unloaded, but in the second run the cog is loaded)

Since I'm already here, please let me know if there are any improvements that I could make in my code since I'm somewhat new to python and this is my first time using an API. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when `commands.ExtensionNotLoaded` is raised your code attempts to unload it, but it can't unload a function which isn't loaded. Secondly `commands.ExtensionNotLoaded` isn't raised by `client.load_extension()`, only `client.load_extension()`, because `client.load_extension()` loads extensions and will only run into errors if it is unable to load the function because it is already loaded.

I think the problem is you forgot `[:-3]`, adding the '.py', when unloading the cog

```
@cogs.command(name='list')
async def cogs_list(ctx):
    cog_list = ''
    for extension in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if extension.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension[:-3]}')
            except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** loaded\n'
            else:
                cog_list += f'**{extension[:-3]}** not loaded\n'
                client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension[:-3]}")
                #                                         ^^^
    await ctx.send(f'**BOT COGS:**\n{cog_list}')
```